# PHP extension memcached on MAMP 3.4

Tags: php, memcached, mamp, php-5.6

I have memcached 2.2.0 showing up on phpinfo, but I am unable to implement a project that utilizes this extension. I have been getting this Fatal error: Class 'Memcache' not found. I am running php 5.6.10.

I believe the memcached version might not be compatible with the current php version?

Comment: The class name is `Memcached`, not `Memcache`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I needed to install the PHP Extension memcache, where the Memcache Class is located. I had thought memcached was the new memcache, but I need both extensions for the data objects and daemon to work together.